# Logstash Grok pattern to cut split a string and remove last part

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Below is the field that is filebeat log path, that I need to split with delimiter '/' and remove the log file name in the text.

```
"source" : "/var/log/test/testapp/c.log"
```

I need only this part

```
"newfield" : "/var/log/test/testapp"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do a little of research you can find that this is a trivial question and it has not much complexity. You can use `grok-patterns` to match the interesting parts and differentiate the one you want to retrieve from the one you don't.

A pattern like this will match as you expected, having the `newfield` as you desire:

```
%{GREEDYDATA:newfield}(/%{DATA}.log)
```

Anyway, you can test your Grok patterns with this [tool](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result), and here you have some usefull [grok-patterns](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/groklib/grok-patterns). I recommend you to take a look to those resources.